# apply a function to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm new to using apply:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame({"k1":['2017-03-07','2017-02-07','2017-01-15'],
                 "k2":[1,2,3],})
```

I want to get the data that matches some month. For example: I want to get the month == 2:

```
df[pandas.to_datetime(df.k1).dt.month == 2]
```

But I want to write a function with a parameter can match the month.
this is my function. It doesn't work.

```
def get_month(df, mon=1):
    return df[pandas.to_datetime(df.k1).dt.month == mon]

df.apply(get_month)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your code a bit.  `apply` works per row.

**Code:**

```
def get_month(mon):
    return lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x.k1).month == mon
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"k1": ['2017-03-07', '2017-02-07', '2017-01-15'],
                       "k2": [1, 2, 3], })

print(df[df.apply(get_month(1), axis=1)])
```

**Results:**

```
           k1  k2
2  2017-01-15   3
```